# Posicionamento com display: flex

Tags: html, css, css3, flexbox

Estava fazendo uma página de exercício e tive uma dúvida com `display: flex`. Veja o exemplo. Tenho uma `DIV` centralizada e dentro dela outras `DIVs` menores.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="teste.css">
</head>

<body>

<div class="centro">

    <div class="conteudo" id="um"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="dois"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="tres"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="quatro"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="cinco"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="seis"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="sete"></div>
    <div class="conteudo" id="oito"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

No caso acima usei `justify-content: space-around` e `flex-wrap: wrap`. Nas linhas onde há 3 itens fica legal, mas na última linha onde tem dois ele centraliza.

Sei que isso é por causa do `space-around`. Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma dos itens da última linha ficarem alinhados abaixo (primeira e segunda coluna) mas ainda usando `display: flex` para manter o ajuste do conteúdo conforme a dimensão da janela?

Segue meu CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.centro {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #808080;
    transform: translate(10%,50%);
    padding: 5px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.conteudo {
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border: 5px dashed #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `justify-content` alinha os itens `flex` no `container` de acordo com a direção. A propriedade só funciona se os itens atuais não ocuparem todo o `container`. Isso significa que ao definir `flex: 1`; ou algo similar nos itens, a propriedade não terá mais função.

Logo existem as seguintes propriedades para o `justify-content`, as quais são:

```
// Alinha os itens ao início do container.
justify-content: flex-start;

// Alinha os itens ao final do container.
justify-content: flex-end;

// Alinha os itens ao centro do container.
justify-content: center;

// Cria um espaçamento igual entre os elementos. Mantendo o primeiro grudado no início e o último no final.
justify-content: space-between;
```

**Figura Ilustrativa**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabendo como todas as propriedades do `justify-content` funcionam, você possui diversas opções de fazer do modo que deseja. Abaixo darei um exemplo utilizando o `justify-content: flex-start;`.

O `justify-content: flex-start;` irá alinhar os itens ao início do container, logo ficando deste modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenha em mente que estou utilizando o browser em uma resolução alta, caso eu diminua a resolução irá ficar do seguinte modo (depende da resolução que irá estar):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sabendo-se disto, você pode observar que os últimos conteúdos ficaram alinhados como desejava, porém todos os conteúdos estão "colados" uns aos outros, para solucionar isto é bastante simples, basta apenas adicionar as seguintes propriedades a sua classe `.conteudo`:

```
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

Então você deverá alterar o seguinte no seu `.css`:

- Adicionar o `justify-content: flex-start;` a classe `.centro`
- adicionar margins a classe `.conteudo`

**CSS Modificado:**

```
   .centro {
        width: 80%;
        height: 50%;
        border: 2px solid #808080;
        transform: translate(10%,50%);
        padding: 5px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .conteudo {
        width: 230px;
        height: 230px;
        border: 5px dashed #808080;
        margin-right: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

**Nota**

> Para saber mais sobre Flexbox, acesse este [Guia Completo](https://origamid.com/projetos/flexbox-guia-completo/).